# Disable and hide Navigation back button in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to remove the back button from the navigation pane in ionic . 
I tried using `hide-back-button` , `$ionicHistory` , `$ionicHandleDelegate` but it do=id not serve my purpose. I just dont want to navigate to previous page using "Back" because the menu button serves the purpose.
My html goes like this

```
 <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
 <ion-side-menu-content>
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
      Home
    </ion-item>
    <div ng-repeat = "opt in menuOptions">
        <ion-item ng-click = "toggleOptions(opt)"> 
          {{opt.name}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-repeat = "item in opt.items" ng-show = "opt.show" ng-click = "toggleSubOptions(item)">
          {{item.itemName}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#" ui-sref="app.resetpass">
      Reset Password
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#" ng-click="logout()">
      Logout
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

My Controller goes this way

```
serveApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$auth',function($scope,$state,$auth) {

console.log("App Ctrl");
$scope.menuOptions = [{

{
    name : 'Opt2',
    show : false,
    items : [],
    goTo: "app.page2"
},
{
    name : 'Opt2',
    show : false,
    items : [],
    goTo: "app.page2"
}
];   

$scope.toggleOptions = function (option){
    if(option.items.length != 0){
        //console.log("suboption",option)
        option.show = !option.show; 
    } else {
        //console.log("no sub")
        $state.go(option.goTo);
    }       
};
```

Comment: Why not just remove it from the markup?

Comment: I tried that, but it removes the menu slider button from the page once i navigate to page 2